issues in fetching data from firebase
I have uploaded the data on firebase which has 12,000 products, and each product has multiple sections, firstly I want to fetch one of the sections from each product.
Example: product 1 -> _id, name, price etc.
product 2 -> _id, name, price etc.
I want to fetch _id from all 12,000 products but no matter what I try it is only able to retrieve some 2k data.
This is the python code I have written
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, credentials
import sys
import requests
import logging

# Set the default encoding to utf-8
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize Firebase
cred = credentials.Certificate("credentials.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {"databaseURL": "https://---.firebasedatabase.app/"})

# Create a reference to the Firebase Realtime Database
ref = db.reference("/products")

# Fetch all data directly
def fetch_all_data():
    try:
        # Fetch all products from the database
        data = ref.get()  # This assumes that your data is directly under the /products node
        if data is None:
            logging.warning("No data returned from Firebase.")
        return data
    except (requests.RequestException, firebase_admin._http_client.TransportError) as e:
        logging.error(f"Network error: {e}. Retrying...")
        return fetch_all_data()  # Retry the data fetch

# Fetch all products
products = fetch_all_data()

# Check if the products data is available
if products:
    total_count = len(products)
    id_list = [product.get("_id") for product in products if isinstance(product, dict) and product.get("_id")]

    logging.info(f"Total products with _id: {total_count}")
    logging.info(f"List of _id values: {id_list[:20]}...")  # Print first 20 ids as a sample
else:
    logging.error("No products found in the database")

logging.info("Length of List of _id values: %d", len(id_list))  # Print length of the list


I checked the rules of my realtime database and enabled them as true still it is not giving me 12k data
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true",  
  }
}


The rules can't be the problem, as the Admin SDKs bypass those anyway. You might want to remove that. --- How big is the JSON data under /products? How big is the JSON data you actually need from that?

@FrankvanPuffelen ok I will remove that thank you. under /products I have 12k items and I just want the "_id" from each 12k items

12K is a node count, what I actually mean is the actual data size for the full node and only the IDs. If you prefer you can also provide is a snippet of the data under /products, which allows us to estimate the same.
